# testing suite with swing

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

I'm started to make a "testing suite" in java. I'm currently working on sentence completion type tests. Basically I have a text with placeholders, where the user should put in some text, and which will be evaluated later. I found out that by using `FlowLayout` I could fit the `JLabel`s and `JTextField`s after each other. The problem is when a block of text is too long. It should span into multiple lines, and I'm not sure how to actually do that. And while that's okay, if I push a small text from the end of the line to a new line, but I'm still stuck if the whole text block is longer than the line width.

And I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so is there any **opensource** libraries for testing suites? My googlefu failed.

[image: the desired output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I've found to this problem is using Rob Camick's [`WrapLayout`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/)

`WrapLayout` is essentially an extension of `FlowLayout` which wraps the content when it can no longer fit horizontally.

Check out the linked blog above as it explains why your having the problems you are.

**Updated**

Another option would be to use `JTextPane` and insert fields into, for example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class TestText {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestText();
    }

    public TestText() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
                tp.replaceSelection("Asd, asd, asd, fgh ");
                addField(tp);
                tp.replaceSelection(" more funky text here ");
                addField(tp);
                tp.replaceSelection(" and this must wrap on the edge. The color code of red is: #");
                addField(tp);
                tp.replaceSelection(". ");
                tp.setEditable(false);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(tp));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

            protected void addField(JTextPane tp) {
                JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
                field.setAlignmentY(0.75f);
                tp.insertComponent(field);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Note, the editor itself is not editable, but the text fields are...

Comment: I'll look at this in the morning, but isn't this just rearrange the **whole** JLabel if it can't fit there, instead of splitting?

Comment: Yes, that would be the case.  The other option would be to use `JEditorPane` and add the fields directly into the editor...

Comment: Thank you! I really forgot about `JTextPane`